# Routes - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, route

Queria saber o que significa este $ na definição das rotas, por exemplo :

`route["(.*)-sid-(:num)-(:num)"]  = "services/service/$2/$3";`

O que representa `$2`e `$3`?

Comment: Segundo o [manual](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html): `$route['products/([a-z]+)/(\d+)'] = "$1/id_$2"`; **URL**: `products/shirts/123` -> `$1 = shirts e $2 = id_123`. Representam os parâmetros da rota que você definiu.

Comment: são apenas variáveis que representam o ID e a function que sera passado para a url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

São agrupamentos de caracteres capturados de uma Expressão Regular ou `RegEx`.

Em seu caso, o CodeIgniter pode definir as rotas com os agrupamentos das Expressões Regulares dentro dos parênteses, onde em: `$route["(.*)-sid-(:num)-(:num)"] = "services/service/$2/$3";`, `$2` e `$3` representam respectivamente os grupos de caracteres numéricos `(:num)` e `(:num)` e `$1` captura um grupo de caracteres caso exista `(.*)`

Comment: Explicação perfeita, obrigado!